# I am getting an "Route not defined error" with my form in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have set up a form like this:

```
<!--Registration Form-->

    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'LoginController@try_login', 'class'=>'login_form', 'id'=>'login_reg_form', 'role' => 'form')) }}

        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address', array('class' => 'email')); }}

        {{ Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'password')); }}

        {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

        {{ Form::submit('Click Me!'); }}

    {{ Form::close() }}

    <!--End Form-->
```

Pointing to the login controller.

Here is the controller code:

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Instantiate a new LoginController instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Try_Login
     */
    public function try_login()
    {
        //Do Authentication - Log the user in.

    }

}
```

All seems to be well, but for some reason i get the following error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Route [HomeController@try_login] not defined. (View: /Users/Tapha/../login.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.php`, you have to define a route that your form can access or it will never know what to do when you submit the form. Simply defining `Controller@method` will not suffice.

I assume you're sending your form with `GET` because otherwise you would've provided `'method' => 'post'` in your form creation code.

```
Route::get('login', ['uses' => 'HomeController@try_login']);
```